# Convert jQuery function insertBefore() to before() for appending a hidden input

Tags: javascript, jquery, hidden-field

I have a block of code that uses jQuery to append a hidden field (with appropriate attributes) created by the `attr()` function. I'm currently using the `insertBefore()` function as shown below:

```
$('<input>').attr({
    name: 'token',
    type: 'hidden',
    value: 'value',
}).insertBefore( $('#form_id :submit') );
```

This correctly appends a new hidden DOM input element before the `submit` button of my `#form_id` form, but I'd like to use `before()` instead, as selecting my target before defining the content seems more readable to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just before posting my question above, I tried one more time using `before()` from the ground up, and somehow I succeeded this time. So I decided to post my question and answer (solution) in hopes that it could help someone else trying to do the same in the future:

```
$('#form_id :submit').before(
    $("<input>", {
        name: 'token',
        type: 'hidden',
        value: 'value',
    })
);
```

This code essentially returns a new DOM input element with the set attributes in the `{}` object we passed on. This returned element is the `content` argument we need to pass to `before()` to insert our hidden field before the element in our selector, the `submit` button of our ID in this case.

Comment: The differences in these two insertion methods are clearly explained in the docs

Comment: @charlietfl We know that, but their basic example of `<p>Test</p>` is seriously lacking. Furthermore, the docs don't show how to insert a dynamically-created element, which is what I explained above.

Comment: Fine...creating an element is also jQuery 101

Comment: @charlietfl So that somehow makes my contribution less valuable here? huh.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you.

```
$('#form_id').before('<input type="text" name="token" value="value" />');
```

Comment: I already provided the solution in my answer, which is a better way when your attributes are dynamic values (variables) and not just a static HTML tag, but thanks anyway.